# Android device does not show up in Android Device Chooser, but is listed in adb

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adt

I'm using Eclipse+ADT on Mac OS. I have a Nexus 5 connected via USB, but it does not show up in the Android Device Chooser when I run my app from Eclipse. Actually, it did show up once, and I could deploy my app to the phone, but then it just disappeared from the Android Device Chooser.

The really weird thing is that the device is listed when I run

```
adb devices
```

on the terminal. I even get the debug messages from the phone in Eclipse's LogCat, so it clearly is connected and recognized – but it still doesn't show up in the Device Chooser. I have tried all the solutions proposed here (rebooting the phone, turning debug mode on and off, restarting adb, restarting Eclipse, etc.) – to no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it say "unauthorized" in terminal when running adb devices ?

Comment: @DanielM. No, it gives me the device's serial number.

Comment: I assume you tried closing Eclipse , running adb kill-server then adb devices and reopening eclipse ?

Comment: Does ADB work for any other phone, or for an emulator?  Any chance there is more than one version of ADB installed?  There seem to be a bunch of these questions in the last few days - did you just download a new SDK version, upgrade your operating system, or anything like that?

Comment: I faced similar issue. I was able to detect my device, debug, build ...everything was fine till yesterday but the next day I was unable to see the device in "Android device chooser" but under the Device tab, it clearly showed the device. I tried all of the stuff you tried n plus my own stuff.... but everything was in vain. Accidentally I dragged the empty list of devices in "Android device chooser" Suddenly the device appeared. It was like WTF..My 6 hours of time lost on a really silly issue. Coding Android on Eclipse SUCKS!!!. I guess this comment matches @blazeline's answer. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eerily similar to what I just spent the last hour figuring out. OS X, Nexus 5, shows up in adb devices, tried everything under the sun.

In my case, it turned out that even though the device wasn't listed, I was able to press the OK button and it launched just fine. (seen below)

[image: OK even though no device is listed]

I'm not sure if it also helped, but before I stumbled upon that solution, I edited my Launch config options to change from "Always prompt to pick device" to "Launch on all compatible devices/AVS'S" and selected the "Active Devices" options. I ran that and it worked! I expected the device to start showing up in the above menu afterwards, but it didn't. Then I realized it didn't matter and I could hit OK and it would build. Go figure.

Comment: That's definitely not how it's supposed to be, but it does work :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I couldn't see my Nexus 4 in the Device Chooser list even though I could see it in the DDMS. I found out it is just hidden from view. Click the device chooser list and scroll up with your mouse wheel. The device should now be visible in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of  blazeline worked for me but it was a little bit tricky to scroll up to make appear the device.

Another way to do it and to make appear the device more clearly is to disconnect your device when the Device Chooser List is opened and to reconnect it. It will clearly appear now in the device chooser list.

Eclipse is really sometimes strange...

Answer (score -1):

My case was same as mentioned here and obviously i did all tricks with no success but solution was very logic:
device i was missing in pickup list had lower API then allow by AndroidManifest.xml